# How do I use homebrew less instead of system less?

Tags: homebrew

I've installed `less` via

```
homebrew install less
```

but `less` starts the system version of `less`, not the one installed via homebrew. `which less` shows:

```
$ which -a less
/usr/local/bin/less
/usr/bin/less
```

where `/usr/local/bin/less` is a symlink to `../Cellar/less/487/bin/less` (homebrew `less`)
and `/usr/bin/less`  is the system `less`. `echo $LESS` returns nothing. How can I start homebrew `less` instead of system `less` by default?

Comment: why would you want to?

Comment: @WalrustheCat the macOS version of `less` is from 2013, specifically version 458. The current Homebrew version is 487. Some enhancements have been made and bugs have been fixed between versions.

Comment: @ ssdecontrol exactly. @WalrustheCat why I would want to doesn't really matter, or does it? However, if you think replacing system less might have undesired side effect, please share your thoughts.

Comment: @Cpt_Jauchefuerst just curious mang

Comment: This question / answer would also apply to other programs like e.g. nano

Comment: One reason to use the brew version is that it supports saving with `s`, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/455202/how-to-save-input-of-less-to-file-as-explained-in-the-man-doc/455203#455203 I had the same problem that after brew installing it was still using the system version. Restarting my shell (zsh) fixed it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This might be due to bash's hash table of commands in `PATH` still using the old value. Remove the hash of `less`, or clear the hash, so that bash re-searches `PATH`:

```
hash -d less
# or, hash -r
```

You can also manually add a path to the table:

```
hash -p /usr/local/bin/less less
```

From [the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Search-and-Execution) (emphasis mine):

> If the name is neither a shell function nor a builtin, and contains no
>   slashes, Bash searches each element of `$PATH` for a directory
>   containing an executable file by that name. **Bash uses a hash table to
>   remember the full pathnames of executable files to avoid multiple `PATH`
>   searches** (see the description of `hash` in [Bourne Shell Builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins)). **A
>   full search of the directories in `$PATH` is performed only if the
>   command is not found in the hash table.**

Comment: Worked like a charm. `$hash -d less` resulted in `-bash: hash: less: not found` but `$hash -r` did the job.

Comment: What to do if you use `zsh` which is now the default?

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer `hash -r` or `rehash` according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/36547391/2072269

Answer (score 4):

If homebrew is correctly installed `/usr/local/bin/` is checked before `/usr/bin/`. Check this with `echo $PATH`, this will show you the path's the OS is trying to find the command you entered and it is trying them in the order that is shown.

***A little fancier***
using the bash shell:

```
echo $PATH | awk '{ n = split($0, paths, ":"); for (i=0; ++i <= n;) print i, paths[i] }'
```

(using the [fish](https://fishshell.com) shell):

```
echo $PATH | awk '{ n = split($0, paths, " "); for (i=0; ++i <= n;) print i, paths[i] }'
```

This will show an numbered list of the path's tried. Mine shows

```
1 /Users/peter/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin
2 /usr/local/sbin
3 /usr/local/bin
4 /usr/bin
5 /bin
6 /usr/sbin
7 /sbin
8 /Library/TeX/texbin
```

The system will traverse the directories in the above order looking for commands, in your case `less`. If it's not in the first one, it will try the next one until it runs out of options and throw up an error.

So if your `echo $PATH` shows similar results as mine you are using the homebrew version of less.

Comment: In the Unix spirit, small tools that do one job and do it well-  `echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n' | nl`

Comment: That's much more elegant. I didn't know about `nl`, and as they say _when you have a hammer, everything looks like a nail_.

Comment: `/usr/local/bin` is indeed checked before `/usr/bin` but the /usr/bin/less was in the bash's hash table so I had to `$hash -r`.

Answer (score 0):

I **restarted the shell**, and this fixed the problem. Maybe a caching issue.

If this doesn't help, make sure that `/opt/homebrew/bin` appeares above `/usr/bin` when running

```shell
echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n' | nl`
```